# Display sql table with a php loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to loop through a mysql table and display the attributes. For some reason it will only display one line of data. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $query = "SELECT DATE(date) AS date, type, time_in_minutes, heartrate, calories FROM exercise_log WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
         or die('Error querying database.');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['date'] . $row['type'] . $row['time_in_minutes'] .
            $row['heartrate'] . $row['calories'] . 
           '<ahref="removelog.php"><img id="trash" src="images/trashcan.png" alt="Profile Picture"></a><hr/><br />';
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: you have used where condition on id. if it is primary key then obviously you will get only one row

Comment: Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @ yes remove where condition

Answer (score 0):

Check the count of the resultset by using the code below

```
      $query = "SELECT DATE(date) AS date, type, time_in_minutes, heartrate, calories FROM exercise_log WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
             or die('Error querying database.');
       $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['date'] . $row['type'] . $row['time_in_minutes'] .
                $row['heartrate'] . $row['calories'] . 
               '<ahref="removelog.php"><img id="trash" src="images/trashcan.png" alt="Profile Picture"></a><hr/><br />';
        }

        mysqli_close($dbc)

;
```

This will show you how many records are being fetched by your query